# TypeScript in Flutter WebView

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, flutter, webview

Can i run TypeScript in the Flutter WebView?. While load a website in the Webview i need to run TypeScript is it possible in the flutter. Im facing an issue to run video while loading, so i need to run it manually from the app.

```
  WebView(
    initialUrl: privacyUrl,
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    gestureNavigationEnabled: false,
    debuggingEnabled: true,
    onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
      webController = controller;
    },
    onPageFinished: (url) {
      // This is JS code get from web. so i need corresponding TypeScript method.
      webController.runJavascriptReturningResult(
          "javascript:(function() { document.getElementById('spot-video').play(); })()");
    },
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Typescript needs to be compiled into Javascript before running on the web, even on the Typescript targets (like the web ), writing a Typescript code and trying to run it directly will fail ( without compiling it to Javascript). websites and browsers.. know Javascript, not Typescript.

In your case I would say that the best solution you have is to write a Typescript code in a separate project, then make sure that it does work, then compile it to Javascript and use it in your  `runJavascriptReturningResult` method.

and since `runJavascriptReturningResult` takes a `String`,  there is an option that you can make it using a third-party Typescript compiler.